# How should we set widgets values in Android?

Tags: android, android-widget

I was looking at my code and I realized that there are at least 3 ways of getting widget's reference in code:

First one (before onCreate):

```
private TextView textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    }
```

Second one (in onCreate):

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        final TextView textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
     }
```

Third one (creating out and setting in onCreate):

```
private TextView textView;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

            textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
         }
```

What is the difference between this 3 methods? When should I use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first does not guarantee that your widget is actually instantiated, it is not within the onCreate.

Second will be instantiated, but its value can not be changed because it becomes a constant to be the final.

Third, it is a global variable that will be instantiated in onCreate and you can use it in any other part of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You must call `setContentView()` prior calling `findViewById()`, therefore on 1st approach will give you `null` all the times. 2nd and 3rd are the same with the exception for `final` keyword, but this is [Java feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java)), not Android's.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call `findViewById()` then the call should be anywhere after `setContentView`. Not before that like in your first option. Your third option creates an instance variable, use it only if the textview will be accessed a lot throughout the class, otherwise just call `findViewById` wherever you need it.